# I'm getting a CORS when i try to communicate with my proxy server

Tags: node.js, express, google-maps-api-3, cors

Good day everyone, Please I need your help
I wanted to use Google places api to get the nearest hospital in the user location, I tried implementing it in the frontend directly but I kept getting a CORS error, "https://res-q.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

A friend of mine suggested I set up  a simple proxy server to get rid of the CORS error. When i set it up and hosted it local, it worked fine , I was able to use the Google places api. But after I hosted the proxy server on vercel I got the same error again.

In summary it works in local host but gave Cors error when i made a request to the the server on vercel.

This the frontend function I'm trying to run:
`

```
const fetchNearbyHospitals = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('https://res-q-google-api-proxy-server.vercel.app/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json', {
            params: {
                location: `${userLocation.latitude},${userLocation.longitude}`,
                radius: 1500,
                type: 'hospital',
                key: 'the api key was here' 
            }
            
            });

            const hospitalData = response.data.results;
            console.log("Response: ", response)
            console.log("Hospital fetched: ", hospitalData)
            if (hospitalData.length > 0) {
                let closestHospital = hospitalData[0];
                let closestDistance = calculateDistance(userLocation, closestHospital.geometry.location);
                for (let i = 1; i < hospitalData.length; i++) {
                    const hospital = hospitalData[i];
                    const distance = calculateDistance(userLocation, hospital.geometry.location);
                    if (distance < closestDistance) {
                        closestHospital = hospital;
                        closestDistance = distance;
                    }
                }
                setClosestHospital(closestHospital);
                console.log("Closest Hospital: ", closestHospital)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching nearby hospitals:', error);
        }
    };
```

While the proxy server code is

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});


// Define your route to proxy requests to the Google Maps API
app.get('/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { location, radius, type, key } = req.query;
        const apiUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json`;

        const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
            params: {
                location,
                radius,
                type,
                key
            }
        });

        // Forward the response from the Google Maps API to the client
        res.json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error proxying request:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});
// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Don't use the web service. Google Maps has a Javascript API for use in Javascript apps and it comes with a Places library and the [Places Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service?hl=en).